# Testing Touch Screens

Tags: automated-tests, touchscreen

My colleagues who work with Point of Sales (POS) want to test how their application responds to unusual touch-screen processes.

For example: There's a login page....what happens if the user touches the wrong part of the screen or maybe keeps touching a button? A certain degree of randomization would be desirable.

They're NOT interested in the touch-screen technology functionality, just user madness!!

So I need to simulate random stabbings - automated to be run frequently and oh, it's a Windows app!

Anyone got any bright ideas please?